# Play! Image Resizing causes old files stored on the server

Tags: image-processing, playframework

I want to resize uploaded images to a small version and thumbnail version. Therefore I am using the great module S3. This is working fine and all images are uploaded to s3.
But after a few uploads I realised that the resized images are stored on the disk as well and are not deleted.

My code:

```
public static Picture save(File file, Recipe recipe){

    File picture = new File(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    //Resize main picture
    Images.resize(file, picture, 600, 600, true);

    File thumbNail = new File(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    //Resize thumbnail
    Images.resize(file, thumbNail, 260, 190, true);

    Picture pic = new Picture();
    pic.pictureFileName = file.getName();
    pic.picture = new S3Blob();

    pic.thumbPictureFileName = file.getName();
    pic.thumbPicture = new S3Blob();

    pic.recipe = recipe;
    try{
        pic.picture.set(new FileInputStream(picture), MimeTypes.getContentType(file.getName()));
        pic.thumbPicture.set(new FileInputStream(thumbNail), MimeTypes.getContentType(file.getName()));
        pic.save();

    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        Logger.error(e, "FileNotFound");
    }

    return pic;
}
```

How can I delete the files after uploading? Normaly I would wait for the stream when its finished but I dont know when its finished and so I cant delete the file.

Comment: How do you infer that the S3 storage operation is asynchronous? Why don't you store the files to a temporary directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Samuel commented I was expecting an async behaviour which is not correct.

After resizing and uploading the pictures and just delete them with file.delete() and thats it!